# Display differet price on frontend

Tags: magento2, product, price, plugin, magento2.4

I want to display different price on the frontend. I just want to display it don't want to show in add it cart.

I have created a product with zero price and I want to show 5$ price for that item. I tried to use AfterGetPrice Plugin shown here:  https://webkul.com/blog/set-custom-product-price-when-displaying-on-front-end-in-magento-2/

It's showing different price on the frontend but if user add to cart that price is also going in to cart and checkout.  I don't want to send that price to cart and checkout.

How can I display custom price only?

Answer (score 0):

You can just hide the price for that product and add a custom block to the price section. This will fulfill your problem.